# On distribution of size of integer points in a subspace associated to a linear diophantine equation

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory, geometry-of-numbers, probabilistic-number-theory, diophantine-geometry

Take $A,B,C,D$ pairwise coprime with $$n<A,B,C,D<2n$$ $$
n/4<|A−B|,|C−D|,|A−C|,|A−D|,|B−C|,|B−D|$$ and consider the space of solutions to $ACa+ADb+BCc+BDd=0$ spanned by $3\times 4$ matrix
$$N=\begin{bmatrix}
-D&C&0&0\\
-B&0&A&0\\
0&0&-D&C
\end{bmatrix}.$$

Denote the $\Bbb Q$-linear space spanned by rows of $N$ by $T_{A,B,C,D}\subseteq\Bbb Q^4$ and denote the set of non-zero $\Bbb Z$ vectors in $T_{A,B,C,D}$ by $T_{A,B,C,D}[\Bbb Z]^\star$.

Consider the quantity $\mu(A,B,C,D)=\min_{v\in T_{A,B,C,D}[\Bbb Z]^\star}\|v\|_\infty$ where $\|v\|_\infty$ is largest coordinate by magnitude of vector $v$. It is clear $\mu(A,B,C,D)\leq|a|,|b|,|c|,|d|$ at any $a,b,c,d$ with $ACa+ADb+BCc+BDd=0$ and $|a|+|b|+|c|+|d|\neq0$.

> 1. Is there a name for $\mu(A,B,C,D)$?
> 2. How is $\mu(A,B,C,D)$ distributed as a function of $A,B,C,D$ chosen with the constraints above (at least consider $A,B$ and $C,D$ each a coprime pair and $n<A,B,C,D<2n$) and what is its average value?

Simulations and heuristics suggest a value between $\Omega(n^{1/2})$ and $\Omega(n^{2/3})$ with $\Omega(n^{2/3})$ being the most likely possibility (at least probability $>1/n^\epsilon$ at any fixed $\epsilon>0$) of lower bound  at least when $A,B,C,D$ are prime and hence is also the expected value at least when $A,B,C,D$ are prime.

Note here I am interested in *lower bound* in probabilities and expected value. There are worse case counterexamples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We will assume that $n<A,B,C,D<2n$ and $\gcd(A,B)=\gcd(C,D)=1$.
For $x,y,z\in\mathbb{Q}$, we write $v(x,y,z)$ for the vector
$$\pmatrix{\frac{x}{C}&\frac{y}{C}&\frac{z}{C}}N\in\mathbb{Q}^4.
$$

**Lemma 1.** For $x,y,z\in\mathbb{Q}$, it holds that
$v(x,y,z)\in\mathbb{Z}^4$
iff $x,y,z\in\mathbb{Z}$ and the following conditions hold:
$$\begin{eqnarray*}
  xD+yB\equiv 0\pmod{C},\\
  zD-yA\equiv 0\pmod{C}.\\
  \end{eqnarray*}
$$

**Proof.** A direct calculation shows
$$v(x,y,z)
  =\pmatrix{\frac{-yB-xD}{C}&x&\frac{yA-zD}{C}&z},
$$
which immediately shows the implication from right to left.
Assume then that the vector belongs to $\mathbb{Z}^4$.
Then obviously $x,z\in\mathbb{Z}$.
It follows that $yA,yB\in\mathbb{Z}$,
which implies $y\in\mathbb{Z}$ by the assumption $\gcd(A,B)=1$.

We will call $x,y,z$ such as above *witnesses* for
$\mu(A,B,C,D)\le\|v(x,y,z)\|_\infty$.

**Lemma 2.** For $x,y,z\in\mathbb{Q}$, it holds that
$$\frac{\max(|x|,|y|,|z|)}{4}\le\|v(x,y,z)\|_\infty\le 4\max(|x|,|y|,|z|).
$$
**Proof.** Write $v(x,y,z)=\pmatrix{u&x&v&z}$.
For the first inequality, it suffices to note that
$$|y|=\frac{|vC+zD|}{A}\le\frac{C}{A}|v|+\frac{D}{A}|z|\le 2(|v|+|z|)\le 4\|v(x,y,z)\|_\infty.
$$
For the second inequality, we get
$$|u|\le\frac{B}{C}|y|+\frac{D}{C}|x|\le 2(|x|+|y|)\le 4\max(|x|,|y|,|z|)
$$
and similarly the same bound for $v$.

**Theorem 1.** There is a constant $K$ (independent of $n$) such that for all choices of $A,B,C,D$ as above, it holds that $\mu(A,B,C,D)<Kn^{2/3}$.

**Proof.** For $y\in\mathbb{N}$, let $f(y)$ and $g(y)$ be the unique integers such that $f(y)D+yB\equiv 0\pmod{C}$, $g(y)D-yA\equiv 0\pmod C$, and $0\le f(y),g(y)<C$. They are unique and exist because $\gcd(C,D)=0$. Let $M={}^\lceil\root 3\of{2n}\,{}^\rceil$. By the usual pigeonhole argument, there are $y_1,y_2$ such that $0\le y_1<y_2\le M^2$, $|f(y_1)-f(y_2)|\le M^2$, and $|g(y_1)-g(y_2)|\le M^2$. Now set
$$\begin{eqnarray*}
  x&=&f(y_1)-f(y_2),\\
  y&=&y_1-y_2,\\
  z&=&g(y_1)-g(y_2).\\
  \end{eqnarray*}
$$
By Lemma 1 and the definition of $f$ and $g$, it follows that $x,y,z$ are witnesses for
$\mu(A,B,C,D)\le\|v(x,y,z)\|_\infty$.
By Lemma 2, this implies
$$
  \mu(A,B,C,D)\le 4\max(|x|,|y|,|z|)\le 4M^2.
$$

**Theorem 2.** There is a constant $L$ such that for $A,B,C,D$ chosen randomly from all possibilities satisfying the assumptions given at the beginning of this answer, the probability of $\mu(A,B,C,D)$ being below a given limit $m$ is less than $Lm^3/n^2$.

**Proof.** First, fix $C$ and $D$ satisfying the assumptions, and an integer $m>1$. There is a constant $L_1>0$ such that there are at least $L_{1}n^2$ choices for $A,B$. Assume $A,B$ are chosen so that $\mu(A,B,C,D)<m$. Let $x,y,z$ witness this. Then $|x|,|z|<m$. Moreover, $|y|<4m$ by Lemma 2. So, consider $y$ such that $-4m<y<4m$. Let $k=\gcd(y,C)$, and let $y'=y/k,C'=C/k$. For every pair $x',z'$, there are unique $A',B'$ such that $0\le A',B'<C'$ and the following hold:
$$
  \begin{eqnarray*}
  x'D+y'B'\equiv 0\pmod {C'},\\
  z'D-y'A'\equiv 0\pmod {C'}.\\
  \end{eqnarray*}
$$
Moreover, for each pair $A',B'$ there are $k^2$ pairs $A,B$ such that $0\le A,B<C$ and $A\equiv A'\pmod {C'}$, $B\equiv B'\pmod {C'}$. There are no more than $2\lceil m/k\rceil$ choices for $x'$ such that $|kx'|<m$. So, for each choice of $y$, there are fewer than $5m^2$ possibilities for the pair $A,B$. Altogether, there are fewer than $10m^3$ choices for $A,B$ such that $\mu(A,B,C,D)<m$, out of at least $L_{1}n^2$. So, we may choose $L=10/L_{1}$.

Comment: We need a lower bound on probability. Upper bound on probability means nothing. We need something like $P(\mu(A,B,C,D)<m)=\Omega(\frac1{n^\epsilon})$ at any fixed $\epsilon>0$. If that is possible is unclear right?

Comment: I think I see your intention here. $P(\mu(A,B,C,D)<n^{2/3−\epsilon})<L/n^{2\epsilon}$ from Claim $3.$ and so we have $P(\mu(A,B,C,D)>n^{2/3−\epsilon})>1−L/n^{2\epsilon}$? right? Is that your intention? If so this will be really great.

Comment: Yes, exactly. I proved your conjecture with an explicit bound on the probability of exceptions.

Comment: Does similar probability estimate work for https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2456368/on-largest-box-not-containing-integer-vector-solutions-ii? I look for lower bound there as well.

Comment: Your other question does look pretty similar, but I can't say quickly if the same technique works.

Comment: If $|A−B|,|C−D|,|A−C|,|A−D|,|B−C|,|B−D|$ are all distinct but very small do such probabilities still hold?

Comment: @TaneliHuuskonen What do you mean by 'By the usual pigeonhole argument'?

Answer (score 1):

This is a partial answer in one direction. Let $k=\lceil n/6\rceil$, and let
$$A=6k+1, B=10k+1, C=9k+1, D=8k+1.
$$
The numbers $A,B,C,D$ are pairwise coprime, larger than $n$, and all their differences are at least $n/6$. It is straightforward to check that
$$\pmatrix{\frac{1}{C}&\frac{1}{C}&\frac{3}{C}}N=\pmatrix{-2&1&-2&3}.
$$
Moreover, if $n>25$, then $A<D<C<B<2n$. So, for all $n$ large enough, there are $A,B,C,D$ satisfying the given conditions such that $\mu(A,B,C,D)\le 3$.

Comment: Such choices that you make where you can have gcd of all coordinates very high are exceedingly rare. I still think with high probability lower bound $\Omega(n^{2/3})$ works.

Comment: That is actually true. I will add a proof.

Comment: I meant your conjecture. I don't see any error in my own claim either.

Comment: your specific claim is good.